# Hash em um serviço do tipo GET

Tags: javascript, rest

Tenho um serviço onde faço uma requisição do tipo GET que faz uma pesquisa nos grupos da minha aplicação, o problema está que o usuário criou um grupo chamado `#nome-do-grupo`, e quando ele vai fazer a pesquisa pelo nome e ele coloca o hash, a pesquisa da erro porque não tem como mandar o hash para a requisição no server.

Tentei usar o `encodeURIComponent` mas a pesquisa não rolou, comecei a fazer um regex para remover os hashs da string, mas teria que prever o máximo de outros caracteres zuados que ele pode colocar então ficou enviável.

Se alguém já passou por isto, como vocês procedem neste caso ?

Comment: Quando você utiliza `encodeURIComponent`, a string é escapada como `%23nome-do-grupo`? Talvez seja o caso da falta do decode no lado do servidor?

Comment: E ai cara blz, usei o `encodeURIComponent` e não estava rolando porque havia um outro script que estava pegando o termo e dando um outro `escape` nele então estava ficando %2523nome-do-grupo, tirei este `escape` e funcionou como você descreveu, depois tive outros problemas com os demais caracteres e fiz isso aqui `encodeURIComponent(str).replace(/[!'()]/g, escape).replace(/\*/g, '')` ai funcionou corretamente.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depois de quebrar um pouco a cabeça e ter problemas com outros caracteres fiz esta função e funcionou corretamente:

```
encodeURIComponent(str).replace(/[!'()]/g, escape).replace(/\*/g, '')
```

O problema que tinha era que depois do `encodeURIComponent` havia um outro script que dava um `escape` deixando o parâmetro da url desta forma `%2523` (no caso de hash na pesquisa) então tirei este `escape`, depois usei o regex porque o `encodeURIComponent` não consegue 'encodar' estes caracteres ~!*()' e no final dei um replace no * por nada.